# Ошибка при отправке запроса к БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7

Доброе время суток. Столкнулся с проблемой: запись из форм не отправляется в БД. Формируется запрос ($sql), но при попытке отправить в базу - ничего не происходит. Коннект с базой есть (MySQL 8.0, php 7.1). С php столкнулся не так давно, буду рад услышать умных людей.

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'beldum_1';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

error_reporting(E_ERROR);
if(isset($_POST['addVod']))
{
    $vod_fio = $_POST['Вод_фио'];
    $vod_dr = $_POST['Вод_др'];
    $vod_tel = $_POST['Вод_тел'];
    $vod_address = $_POST['Вод_адрес'];
    $category = $_POST['Категория'];
    $vod_dop = $_POST['Вод_доп'];
   if(!$connect){
      echo ('unable to connect to database');
   }
   else {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO beldum_1.voditel (id, FIO, Date_b, Address, Category, Phone, Prim) VALUES ('NULL','$vod_fio','$vod_dr','$vod_address','$category','$vod_tel','$vod_dop')";
   $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
      // SUCCESS STUFF
       echo "SUCCESS";
      } else {
      echo "Error";
      // error stuff
      }
   } // end else
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя был плохо сформирован sql-запроc
До:
$sql = "INSERT INTO beldum_1.voditel (id, FIO, Date_b, Address, Category, Phone, Prim) VALUES ('NULL','$vod_fio','$vod_dr','$vod_address','$category','$vod_tel','$vod_dop')";

После:
$sql = "INSERT INTO `voditel`(`id`, `FIO`, `Date_b`, `Address`, `Category`, `Phone`, `Prim`) VALUES (NULL, '$vod_fio', '$vod_dr', '$vod_address', '$category', '$vod_tel', '$vod_dop')";

Comment: столкнулся с подобной проблемой снова при формировании другого запроса (как ни странно, более легкого). Не подскажите, в чем именно допускаю ошибку,
помимо удаления названия БД и ' ' вокруг NULL?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO organ(Name_org) VALUES('$organ')"; 
на примере такого запроса. При его выводе я вижу, что оно захватывает данные из формы, передает их в переменную, формирует следующий запрос:

INSERT INTO organ(Name_org) VALUES('Тест')

однако БД его не обрабатывает

Comment: Запрос обрабатыааться будет в том случии, если у тебя все остальные значения установлены как NULL (это делается при создании/редакции таблице)